# Why the following array returns false?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to solve given problem:

"Sudoku is a number-placement puzzle. The objective is to fill a 9 × 9 grid with numbers in such a way that each column, each row, and each of the nine 3 × 3 sub-grids that compose the grid all contain all of the numbers from 1 to 9 one time.

Implement an algorithm that will check whether the given grid of numbers represents a valid Sudoku puzzle according to the layout rules described above. Note that the puzzle represented by grid does not have to be solvable"
Example grid is:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '1', '4', '.', '.', '2', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '6', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '1', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '6', '7', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '9'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '8', '1', '.'],
        ['.', '3', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '6'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '7', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '5', '.', '.', '.', '7', '.']]
```

and the expected outcome is true.

I wrote following code to solve this problem :

```
boolean sudoku2(char[][] grid) {
for(int i =0; i < 9 ; i++){
    char [] zeroTab = new char[]{'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'} ;
    char [] zeroTab1 = new char[]{'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'} ;
    for(int g = 0; g < 9; g++){
        if(grid[i][g] != '.'){
            Integer k = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(grid[i][g]));
            if(zeroTab[k-1] == '0'){
                zeroTab[k-1] = grid[i][g];
            }
            else return false;
        }
        if(grid[g][i] != '.'){
            Integer c = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(grid[g][i]));
            if(zeroTab1[c-1] == '0'){
                zeroTab1[c-1] = grid[g][i];
            }
            else return false;
        }
    }
}
    return true;
```

}

And it passes 17/20 tests. For the grid bellow my code returns true and I don't know why expected outcome here is false. Can someone please explain to me why is that the case?

```
[[".",".",".",".",".",".","5",".","."], 
 [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."], 
 [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."], 
 ["9","3",".",".","2",".","4",".","."], 
 [".",".","7",".",".",".","3",".","."], 
 [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."], 
 [".",".",".","3","4",".",".",".","."], 
 [".",".",".",".",".","3",".",".","."], 
 [".",".",".",".",".","5","2",".","."]]
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging through the code? In particular, you could put breakpoints on both of those `return false` statements, and look at the point at which it's returning false. I'd expect anyone trying to help you to have to do exactly that to start with, so it makes sense for you to do so too.

Comment: As an aside, it feels like it would be easier to represent the incoming grid as a `string[]`, so that your tests don't need any commas or quotes...

Comment: I think my problem is more about understanding a problem, than about the code. I don't know why my code should return false, rather than true. I looked at that array over and over and still cannot find the reason why it should return false.

Comment: Oh - in that case, this is really about Sudoku rather than code. It would help if you would edit the post to make that clearer. (It's also off-topic for Stack Overflow, but I can understand why you might not see that to start with.) As noted by Erwin Smout, the bottom centre 3x3 grid has 3 twice.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try to do better next time.

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make - and it was great that you included the code and the failing test. That bodes well for future questions :)

Answer (score 1):

The number 3 appears twice in the lower middle square grid.

(and it looks to me like you wrote no code at all to test for the square sub-grids)

Answer (score 0):

You only checked rows and columns but didn't check each 3x3 sudoku box.
Here is the code in Swift with all test cases passed.

```
func sudoku2(grid: [[Character]]) -> Bool {       
    var i = 0
    while(i < grid.count) {
        var columnArr = [Character]()
        var rowArr = [Character]()
        var j = 0        
        while(j < grid[i].count) {
            if grid[j][i] != "." {
                if columnArr.contains(grid[j][i]) {
                    return false
                }
                columnArr.append(grid[j][i])
            }
            if grid[i][j] != "." {
                if rowArr.contains(grid[i][j]) {
                    return false
                }
                rowArr.append(grid[i][j]) 
            }
            j += 1
        }
        i += 1
    }
    var index = 0
    while(index < 7) {
        var index2 = 0
        while(index2 < 7) {
            var myGrid = [Character]()
            for i in index...index + 2 {
                for j in index2...index2 + 2 {
                    if (grid[i][j] != ".") {
                        if(myGrid.contains(grid[i][j])) {
                            return false
                        }
                        myGrid.append(grid[i][j])
                    }
                }
            }
           index2 += 3  
        }
        index += 3
    }
    return true
}
```